# (How) can I change the time until the screensaver kicks in from the command line?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, screensaver, command-line-arguments

As the title asks (Windows 7). (How) can I change the time until the screensaver kicks in from the command line? Is it even possible?

Normally I am happy with a 5 minute setting, but occasionally I want to make it longer. I would like the two lengths bound to hot-keys (I know how to do that).

I guess I could record two macros and use those, but I just wondered if there are any command line options (including registry updates) that I can use to tell Windows to start the screen saver after X minutes of inactivity.

(please note, I do not want to start the screen saver immediately; I want to change the length of time Windows will wait before starting it)

Thanks in advance.

---

[Answer] I finally used a variation on the answer from @Gjordis - but all credit goes to him.

I didn't see why we needed 3 operations : add, delete then rename and reduced that to two.

Since I want to bind to a hotkey, I need to execute two comamnds in one. Normally, one can separate the commands with a semicolon and issue them on one line (e.g `dir c:;dir d:`). That gave errors with the `reg` command, so in the end I have two batch files. The contens are identitcal, only the duration changes.

On strange thing - the value is correctly written to the registry, but Control Panel/Personalize/Screen saver does not alwys update its GUI. However, I tested and the screen saver does behave as expected.

```
@echo off
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /t REG_SZ /d 180 /f
```

If this helps you, please upvote the question ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /t REG_SZ /d 600 /f
```

The value 600 is in seconds, = 10minutes
 Interestingly, as pointed, this works only the first time. On next change, you need to make a new key  like so :

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOutTemp /t REG_SZ /d 300 /f
```

Then delete the old one

```
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut /t REG_SZ /d 600 /f
```

Then copy the new one to the right name

```
reg copy "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOutTemp "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v ScreenSaveTimeOut
```

Hopy this works, and you do not destory your computer, but since you did not have this registry value, i don't think deleting it can be that horrible.

REG documentation here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: That works :-)   The first time only :-(   presumably because I didn't have a registry entry the frist time, so could add, but might need to modify subsequently?   +1 for trying. Thanks

Comment: Edited to hopefully work other times too

Comment: +1 Well, that's trange. I can see that it is updating the registry key, but when I right click the desktop (or go via control panel) and choose "peronalize", it still shows 5 mintes on the GUI. If I set 10 seconds via registry, the screen saver does not start after 10 seconds (or even a few minutes). If I set 1 minute in the GUI then it does start after 1 minute (and it updates the registry correctly).

Comment: Perhaps it has a valid value -range

Comment: +1 I used a variation on your answer and have posted it in the qustion above. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this approach (via registry) doesn't work *until reboot*.
Only way to do that *without* PC reboot is to use an API:

https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/utility-to-temporarily-change-the-screensaver.2321339/#post-7442568

but APIs can't be used from a command line, i.e. VB script. Here is the reason:

http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?31534-VBScript-and-API&p=86696#post86696

It could be done by calling utility **SetScrTimeout.exe** (from the first link), but unfortunatelly, this small utility doesn't exist on internet anymore.

Comment: Thanks for that. Perhaps SetScrTimeout.exe can be founds on [the way back machine](https://arhive.org)? I can't check because of the company firewall, but it should be there - everything else is ;-)

Comment: I even tried on ftp servers, but no result. I have found an VB source code for that purpose (http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=504), but I am not able to make and share an exe.

Comment: Any idea which version of VB (I am guessing VN 6)?

Comment: Yes, it is VB6. Sorry for my late reply.

Comment: I can share this program, which is similar **SetScrTimeout.exe**:
 
[link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/pg4wb536il2yz2f/ScrSav.zip/file)

Usage
=====

To set the screensaver timeout value to 60 seconds, use this command:

**ScrSav.exe -t60**

Answer (score 1):

For an alternative to the "single use" utilities described before, AutoHotkey allows to call the Win32 API (and the [SystemParametersInfoA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfoa) function) directly.

The following line does the job:

```
DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", "Uint", 15, "Uint", 360)
```

The `SystemParametersInfoA` function can take multiple parameters, in this case we only need two, `uiAction` and `uiParam`.

- `uiAction`: the code for the action (15 for `SPI_SETSCREENSAVETIMEOUT`).
- `uiParam`: the timeout in seconds (360 in this example).

I tested it in Windows 11 but should work in previous versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works great for me. I doubt it's malware, but I can't guarantee. In windows 11, I download it and create any taskbar icon to pin, right click, goto properties and change the path and icon of the short cut to match SetScrTimeout.exe where I downloaded it.

I've got one (tskbar icon) set to 1 second, and another set to 2400 seconds, which is 40 minuets. I made a hot key in the properties of the shortcuts on the task bar. ctrl+shift+z does one icon and ctrl+shift+x does the other.

If you set your screen timeout to 1 second, it actually take a couple seconds to run, so if you move your mouse, it reinitiates after 2 or 3 seconds. As long as your mouse is moving it won't activate.

Great for when I'm falling asleep after pausing youtube...

example:

c:\users\johndoe\docs\SetScrTimeout.exe 10

https://github.com/DavisNT/SetScrTimeout

https://github.com/DavisNT/SetScrTimeout/releases/download/v1.0.0/SetScrTimeout.exe